# Underground propane supply line

Tags: plumbing, furnace, gas, propane, copper-pipe

I have a 500gal propane tank for my house that sits off the house a little. It appears that the original supply line from the tank to the house is 3/8”ID copper that I need to replace. From regulator to regulator it is 28’ and I want to replace this whole section. In case it matters, the house is in northern Wisconsin.

My question is what size piping SHOULD it be and how deep is it typically supposed to be buried?

Comment: The diameter the supply line "should be" is tied to the number of BTUs/hr (or kW) used by the connected appliances, as well as length of line. It's not a fixed number regardless of what's attached. For instance, if you have a tankless propane water heater, you generally need a much bigger line than you do for a tanked water heater. Also depends if there's a regulator at the house, or only on the tank. *e.g.* https://www.gastite.com/downloads/pdfs/gastite_sizing_tables_propane.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did this - in a different country and with the help of a Registered Gas Installer, I used a plastic sleeved 15mm copper pipe.

This was run in a trench 15 or 20" below ground surface inside a plastic tube about 2".

On refilling the trench there was a plastic warning tape placed 6" above the tube to warn any digging in the future.

Depths etc are to be changed to meet the laws and local regulations in your area, especially the use of a registered gas contractor as the insurance needs certification that the work ws done correctly.